# Multiple Headers in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am new to angular 2 and not sure whether I am doing it right or wrong. So, bear with me please.

There are multiple headers in my application. I want to show different header based on route. How can I do this ?

In the below code, by default page loads Header, Footer and Home Components. I want to load SearchHeader Component when route is Search.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'Search', component: SearchComponent },
{ path: 'SearchHeader', component: SearchHeaderComponent },
{ path: 'Header', component: HeaderComponent },
{ path: 'Footer', component: FooterComponent },
{ path: '', component: HeaderComponent, outlet: 'header' },
{ path: '', component: FooterComponent, outlet: 'footer' },
{ path: '*', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Here is my configuration in Component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: 
'<router-outlet name="header"></router-outlet>
<div class="row"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
<router-outlet name="footer"></router-outlet>
`,
})
```

Comment: By header, you mean the browser's title?

Comment: Is this routing working ?

Comment: @brando not browsers title. I know that, it is different. I am talking about the header and footer of master page like that

Comment: @SimonaMi route is working fine. No issues with route. However I am not sure whether I did it in a right way

Answer (score 0):

create a simple route like

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: DefaultHeaderComponent },
 { path: '', component: CustomHeaderComponent },
 { path: '*', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

In you `AppComponent` simply put

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In you `DefaultHeaderComponent` simply put

```
<app-default-header></app-default-header>
 <app-some-component></app-some-component>
<app-default-footer></app-default-footer>
```

In you `CustomHeaderComponent`

```
<app-custom-header></app-custom-header>
 <app-some-component></app-some-component>
<app-custom-footer></app-custom-footer>
```

Comment: Can you please explain those 2 solutions more. If possible do you have any examples ?